# Help with the NOT (!) Logical Operator

Tags: php, string, logical-operators

I'm looking for help with the NOT (!) logical operator. I'm trying to use it with stripos to require "GOOD" but NOT "BAD". So if "GOOD" appears without "BAD" the loop completes however if "GOOD "and "BAD" appear the loop is skipped... Below is what i have for the first part, i haven't been able to come up with the second half successfully. I've read many resources but just end up confused...

```
if (stripos($data, 'GOOD') !== false)


<?php 
$data = 'GOOD and BAD';
if (stripos($data, 'GOOD') !== false && stripos($data, 'BAD') === false)
{
echo 'Success.';
}
else echo 'Failure.';
?>
```

Comment: Please tag with the appropriate programming language. I bet `stripos` returns a NUMBER (and not a BOOLEAN) though. See the appropriate documentation.

Comment: @pst stripos returns a boolean if the string is not found.

Comment: @Howard Some languages/APIs never cease to amaze me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
if (stripos($data, 'BAD') === false)
```

to check if `'BAD'` is not included? Both conditions can be used together in one if like

```
if (stripos($data, 'GOOD') !== false && stripos($data, 'BAD') === false)
```

Comment: And !== false is usually written == true.

Comment: @Julie not in this case. The return value is either the offset inside the text or the value FALSE. Thus it is not the same (as I must say unfortunately).

Comment: This seems like it would be right however im unable to get it to work, i updated my question with your example i tested.

Comment: @Ryan You wanted to have 'BAD' NOT included. Therefore your example `fails` by construction and is thus working.

Comment: Sorry you're right, perhaps i didnt save an edit during testing. Works great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (stripos($data, 'GOOD') > 0 && stripos($data, 'BAD') == false)
```

Comment: This would return a false positive for the string `BAD and GOOD` (did you mean `=== false`?).